# What is the best way to control Flex + PHP software version?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, version-control, browser-cache

SWho works with cached clients system knows that sometimes you have to update server and client files. So far I've managed to solve partially the problem, by making one call every time the software is opened to ask PHP what version of the software he's in. With the result, I compare to the version that Flex is in and voalá. Problem is, whenever I need to make an emergency update inside the business hour range, it's impossible to know how many clients have the Flex version already opened. 
So to sunup: The cache problem I solved by controlling the version in start-up time, if your browser cached it, the version won't match with the server's app.
The only solution I can think to solve the 'already opened app' problem is to make a gateway between the PHP Services and Flex calls, where I would have to pass the Flex version and compare it inside the gateway, before the service is actually called, although I don't like this solution.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this application from Adobe website. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/airlaunchpad/ It will allow you to build a new test app, and you need to select in the menu : "auto update" property. That will generate all the necessary files for you both for server and client.
The end result will have a server based xml file, and setup in each of the client apps to check on recurring basis if the xml file offers newer version of the application, and if true, automatically downloads and updates it. You can update the "check for update" frequency to your liking in the source code, by default it is tied to the application open event.

This frequent update will check for updates also while app is open, so it should solve your problem.

Comment: Apparently, it's designed for applications deployed in AIR. The app in question runs in a browser (Web-App). Does it still work anyway?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I doubt it: AIR has an update framework built-in, which this application probably targets; Flex web-apps do not have this update framework.

Comment: Then I suggest you order something like Beanstalkapp (has auto-deployment built in) or Github (You will need to use Capistrano), simply store your code in git repository and push update to all necessary locations. THe trick is, if you change the name of swf file it will be refreshed and not catched.